# Skiasharp Ruler segmentation is irregular

Tags: skiasharp

I am having some difficulty in creating a ruler using SkiaSharp. Below is my code and it does not draw the ruler segmentation with correct pixel spacing. Some help is needed in explaining the reason for the irregular line spacing.

```
    canvas.DrawLine( 0, info.Height, 0, info.Height / 2, BlackStroke);
    canvas.DrawLine(info.Width , info.Height, info.Width, info.Height / 2, BlackStroke);

    for (int seg=1; seg <= 23; seg++)
    {
        canvas.DrawLine((info.Width/24) * seg, info.Height, (info.Width / 24) * seg, info.Height/2, BlackStroke);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What you see here is the absence of "pixel snapping" (feel free to google)